# Better way to get an element from a parent by class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Say I want to put a button in an HTML table that gives me the value of the neighbor cell upon clicking it.

I have this sample JQuery code: `console.log($(this).parent().parent().children('.name-cell').get(0).innerText);`

In which `$(this)` is a button in a table cell, the rest of the line gets a neighbor cell with a specific class name `name-cell` and returns its value or text.

This one works but since I'm new to JS I don't know if it's the correct way to do it since it looks very clumsy.
Is there any other way I'm not aware of?

Comment: Show us more code, for our understanding.

Comment: [`$(this).parents(ElementSeletor)`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/#:~:text=parents()%20method%20allows%20us,parent%20to%20the%20outer%20ones.)

Comment: Can you provide Htlm Dome Element treee structure ?

Comment: Sorry the table looks like this 
`
<tr>
 <td>
     <button>This is the button</button> 
 </td>
 <td>
      This is the text I want to get
 </td>
</tr>`
in the example above `$(this)` refers to the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is what you need

```
$(this).siblings('.name-cell').text();
```

Comment: Great!, actually this didn't' work but using `$(this).parent().siblings('.name-cell').text();` worked. Because I have to navigate from the button to its parent the table row in order to access the other table rows.